# MySQL select from users where there are more matches

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to know how to choose the users that have the highest number of columns to match the columns of the logged in user.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

order by sum matches conditions ex:

```
SELECT * FROM table where fColumn = 'name' and column2='value2' or colmun3='value3' 
ORDER BY (
(column2='value2') + (column3='value3')
) DESC
```